# How do I create a Typescript type with a type for a property based on value of another property?

Tags: typescript, types

I have got to create a type for getting survey questions from backend.

`id, description` and `optionType` will be supplied from the backend. Based on the value for optionType, I am trying to add the `options` for the question, which will be shown as a radio button in the frontend.

```
export type QuestionDto<T = OptionMap> = T extends 1
  ? {
      id: number;
      description: string;
      optionType: T;
      options: YesNoOption;
    }
  : T extends 2
  ? {
      id: number;
      description: string;
      optionType: T;
      options: YesNoSomewhatOption;
    }
  : {
      id: number;
      description: string;
      optionType: T;
      options: AgeOption;
    };

type YesNoOption = {
  1: 'Yes';
  2: 'No';
};

type YesNoSomewhatOption = {
  1: 'Yes';
  2: 'No';
  3: 'Somewhat';
};

type AgeOption = {
  1: '1 Year old';
  2: '2 Year old';
  3: '3 Year old';
  4: '4 Year old';
};

export type OptionMap = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4;
```

This is how the type is used while fetching records from backend

```
 return this.httpClient.get<QuestionDto[]>(
      `${environment.apiUrl}/assessments`
    );
```

`options` property is never generated for a question.

Comment: Will the back end return the `options` or the front end should generate them based on the `optionType`?

Comment: options is not returned from backend, front end should generate options based on optionType.

Comment: Please provide a link to your code in the TypeScript Playground that demonstrates the problem. Here's something to get you started: https://tsplay.dev/wjQE2W

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript gets removed on compile time, it has no way of knowing what the API will return. You need to rethink your types. Why does it need to be so strict? You can't use the literal string as a value, as they get removed on compile.

One alternative is to change all the answer types into enums, that way you can call them based on the API response.

Answer (score 0):

My proposed solution is
Based on the question answer:

> options is not returned from backend, front end should generate options based on optionType.

You cannot achieve setting values using type. You need to program it. So you need to define a mapping questionType => Array.

Here is a sample code:
[Runnable code playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=54&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/PQgEBUAsEsGdTqA7pAhgF1ATwPYFcAnUAJQFEBlcUAQQAUBJUAgU3UIDtYBYAKHSwAOzUAEU8zWOmg52AEXQ5iEzAF5QAb16gEAEwBcodngC2AI2YEA3FtA6JAYwLQBUmQclP2Ac2s9tOF2l2cEFmAyMzC18AX15eEGBQcgsAN2h7YQAZVCwLUH4hbj5Q0XFJIIB5QJlQNU0-UABrZixwk3MrGwAbVHMu93RPH15Ynl4C4TFlIPkcWtLpmVmlSVAAMg1QANdOA2oCAhyAHinymSqdgD5taN84ngSSZRoGUAFUAlg81HYdLer2PkSsZUAIhAR7o87LBHM5zKBUF0uv8diEhPk5l04JgcAAzFFBeAgsHQby8ewyVbbIJo5gXQnzdjMJCgACyoKOEQ6ABoaAdjqcdvSZJdLgAKADaNglAEZQLyJZtmq1QDLeT0%20gYAEQATQkWuivPUTRaBgATOresx%20qAtQA5HBa0DRUAAXVd3OlZvloEVxuVBjVoA11u1etgBqNJpVFuDVpt9sdzqjAdAAGZLZrbeQcMZmWh0E6Xe7PQ0JWmfX7o4HM6HbXK9R8tl0dABySNK02gWMhhPextEHAt9vJzsqjNxrNaisD5ttosprsAFlrCaXoFnQ-nzrdHt4roAlHcxjwKZxMO9PswVuhBUF5mKWJI724Fmc5AobweDC%20P3MVNc9TaGeVIAvAajUjItLCpwAB0XisI%20yi-rBkHBKER73No0D4mKACEaGwAeGg2No6CQAQOAskyLKkAcOAEGKAAGDqYLAeBggx6DMH8aFAkI2oACTqE%20t5lDsqEArS0RakxmENKMNgsGwBCAkB2igLBWmib%20pYaQSlI2LcIzHmA1CgLAqDGAIXTCNxqwKG8lEpMI0CYIgSAMY0pJePc5KUpgokrAIlJhHyhxYCc4kzJ%20yjXGoUoNMa0D6KqvJobSNa2A4TgAtqUCIIgfETKqC42MlqVmgADOlUmhOavLQrCeW2gV8BFQC-HCGaZVJboBhLgArLVqL1emjU5c4Oz5TA7XwMVJRpr1rp%20SeIEXh8Xw6MFoXzEFEghZwzCwcSYqPsRAFvJt17IdFMjnfJ-mcEOx1dDgXhipeW07Ud8lAA)

```js
/// This is what your REST API returns
type QuestionDtoRest = {
  id: number;
  description: string;
  optionType: number;
}

/// Service Layer types
type QuestionOption = {
  key: number;
  label: string;
}

type QuestionDto = QuestionDtoRest & { options: Array<QuestionOption>  };


/// Rest API parser and option type mapper

/// descripbe all optionType to list of options mapping
const optionTypeOptions = new Map<number, Array<QuestionOption>>([
  [1 , [ { key: 1, label: "Yes"}, { key: 2, label: "No" } ]],
  [2 , [ { key: 1, label: "Yes"}, { key: 2, label: "No" }, { key: 3, label: "Somewhat" } ]],
  [3 , [ { key: 1, label: "1 Year old'"}, { key: 2, label: "2 Year old'" }, { key: 3, label: "3 Year old'" }, { key: 4, label: "4 Year old'" } ]],
]);


const parseRestQuestion = (restQuestion: QuestionDtoRest): QuestionDto => {
  const options = optionTypeOptions.get(restQuestion.optionType);

  if (!options) {
    throw new Error(`Not supported option type: "${restQuestion.optionType}"`);
  }

  return {
    ...restQuestion,
    options
  };
};

// A sample test to prove it is working


const restResponse: Array<QuestionDtoRest> = [
  { id: 1, optionType: 1, description: "This is option type 1" },
  { id: 20, optionType: 2, description: "This is option type 2" },
  { id: 45, optionType: 3, description: "This is option type 3" },
]



const parsedResponse = restResponse.map((r) => parseRestQuestion(r));

console.log(parsedResponse);
```